# Is this function bounded or not?

Tags: calculus, continuity, dynamic-programming, optimal-control

$f(x) = \left(1-\frac ax\right)^2$

where both $x>0$, $a>0$

Is this function bounded? i.e. is there an M such that $f(x) ≤ M < \infty$ ?

How can I figure this out?

Thanks very much in advance and apologies for notation, I am newbie.

Comment: What have you tried?  Hint:  just take $a=1$ to simplify your life.  What happens if $x$ is very large?  What happens if $x$ is near $0$?

Comment: Thank you very much for editing my question, I have so much to learn. My concern is not with a large x but with x approaching to 0. If x could be 0 then I see it is unbounded, in fact it is infinity, but I would like to know about the vicinity of zero.

Comment: So, take $x=10^{-n}$.  Keeping $a=1$, we see that your expression is just $(1-10^n)^2\sim10^{2n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Let $a > 0$. Then, since $f(x) = (1-\frac{a}{x})^{2} \to \infty$ as $x \to 0+$, the function $f$ is unbounded on $]0, \infty[$.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what I first thought but while I see it clear could x take value zero, I am not quite sure since we are talking of x strictly positive. If the interval is open then it should be bounded, or not? My doubts appeared

Comment: Check the definition. And the function $x \mapsto 1/x$ on $]0, \infty[$ is unbounded.